# writing text into a textbox

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I got a form called Form1 and a rich text box called richtextbox1, which is automatically generated, so it's private.

I got another class that connects to a server, I want to output the status of connecting but I can only access the richtextbox1.Text in the Form1 class, I got 2 possible solutions for this, which would be better or is there a better one that I don't know of?

1. making the textbox public
2. instead of :

   ```
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   Application.Run(new Form1());
   ```

creating a form1 object first and using that to store the form that is running:

```
//somewhere global
Form1 theform = new Form1();


Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(theform);
```

Then using the object somewhere in my connection class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a public property in `Form1` that you can use.

`Form1.cs`

```
public string TextBoxText
{
    get { return myTextBox.Text; }
    set { myTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

You can then set the value from another class.

`AnotherClass.cs`

```
myForm1.TextBoxText = "Current server status";
```

How you get access to `myForm1` depends on how you're calling the other class. For example, you could pass the form into the other class's constructor.

```
private Form1 myForm1 = null;
public AnotherClass(Form1 mainForm)
{
    myForm1 = mainForm;
    myForm1.TextBoxText = "Current server status";
}
```

Comment: the property needs an object that I currently do not have, I could pass the form into the communication constructor though.

Comment: Yes, if you pass it into the constructor you can access it from the communication class later on (and set the property when you do have the object).

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the class that is communicating with the server in Form1, add an event to it and subscribe to it in Form1 when you create it.

Comment: Is the other file a static class or is it created in Form1

Comment: different file, not a static class, not related to form1's class.

Comment: How/where are you instanciating it?

Comment: In the form1 class I'm creating an object of the class.

Comment: You can still do the same thing add an event  to the class that Form1 has knowledge of, subscribe to it,  then have that class subscribe to the event in the communication class and pass it on to Form1